# How to make a Layout listener ignore views on top of it - android

Tags: android, layout, listener, android-linearlayout, ontouchlistener

I have a LinearLayout and I want to see when a user has touched it, and has released their finger. I thought I could do this by adding a onTouch listener and checking the event. This linearLayout holds a bunch of buttons.

My problem isn't the listener not working, it just isn't doing what I thought it would do. The listener only gets activated if ONLY the layout has been touched, which makes sense, but isn't what I want. If the user touches a button inside of the layout the layout listener isn't called, and I want it to be called.

Here is my code:

java code:

```
    ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.CategorySelect_lLayout_noID);
    ll.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                Toast.makeText(CategorySelect.this, "action DOWN called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            } 
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                Toast.makeText(CategorySelect.this, "action Up called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

my xml:

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
android:scrollbars="none"
 >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_lLayout_noID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_1"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_1"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_2"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_3"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_4"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_5"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_6"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_7"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_7" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thanks for reading.

UPDATED CODE FOR COMMENTS:

My main xml file that is inflated from my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/categoryselect_background"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_tv_chooseacat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/CategorySelect_tv_chooseacat"
    android:textColor="#FF5500"
    android:textSize="34dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_settings"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_settings"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
     />

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
android:scrollbars="none"
>

    <com.tdubstudios.soundboard.hungergames.ScrollAbleLinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_lLayout_noID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_cato"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_1"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_cinna"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_effie"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_gale"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_haymitch"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_katniss"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategorySelect_b_peeta"
            style="@style/CustomBLUEButtonTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CategorySelect_b_7" />
    </com.tdubstudios.soundboard.hungergames.ScrollAbleLinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the ScrollAbleLinearLayout class:

```
package com.tdubstudios.soundboard.hungergames;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ScrollAbleLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {


public ScrollAbleLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); // Tell parents not to use this event
    return false; // Tell children not to use this event
}
}
```

Yes I know the naming on some things have changed from my previous code, that is because I changed it to hide what type of app I was making (from search results). However for whatever reason I no long care, so that's the reasoning behind that.

Thanks.

THIRD EDIT:

So I'm currently using

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); // Tell parents not to use this event
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        return false;
    } 
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        return false;
    }


    return true; // Tell children not to use this event
}
```

And it works the way I want it to, however it isn't practical. For it to actually register the button clicks you have to make sure you don't move your finger at all left/right/up/down. It has to be like exactly down and exactly up. I was trying to add a onFling method, and then tracking the distance the finger as moved. And if it has moved less then x amount of pixels then make the main method return false which will allow the buttons to work, but if it was actually a swipe/move then the button doesn't need to get activated. Here is what I mean:

```
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > MORE_THAN_X_INT) {
            booleanVar = false;
            return false;
        }else{
          booleanVar = true;
         }
      return false;
   }
```

Then doing:

```
Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); // Tell parents not to use this event
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        return false;
    } 
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        return false;
    }


    return booleanVar; // Tell children not to use this event
}
```

I think that would work, but I can't test it because there isn't a onFling method for extends LinearLayout

Any suggestions?

Please note my returning true/false might be backwards, I'm not sure it's kind of confusing me. But if someone could lead me in a way to making that onFling method I can mess around with it to get it the correct values.

---

I have

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); // Tell parents not to use this event
    while(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        return true;
    } 
    while(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        return true;
    }


    return false; // Tell children not to use this event
}
```

and my buttons are never click able. But the ontouch listener works perfectly haha :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend extending `LinearLayout` and using `onInterceptTouchEvent` to catch the touch event, then return `true` to force its children to not receive the events.

Something like this:

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return true; // Tell children not to use this event
    }
}
```

And, then in your XML, change `LinearLayout` to `com.yourpackagename.MyLinearLayout`.

**Addendum**: If you want both the `Button`s **and** the `LinearLayout` to receive the event, you can change the `onInterceptTouchEvent` to this:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Whatever touch event code you want, using the "event" variable
    return false; // Allow children to use the event
}
```

Comment: I extend Activity though, there is more to my Activity then this LinearLayout. I just didn't think it was necessary to show the random methods. Or does LinearLayout also include the normal Activity methods?

Comment: No, make a new class, in a separate file. This code actually has nothing to do with the original Activity; let's say you have "MyActivity.java" in package "com.yourapp". You want to create a new file, "MyLinearLayout.java", in the same package, and use the code I detailed above. Then, in your XML file, change the `<LinearLayout>` and `</LinearLayout>` tags to `<com.yourapp.MyLinearLayout>` and `</com.yourapp.MyLinearLayout>` respectively. Basically, what you're doing, is creating a custom `LinearLayout` and using that instead.

Comment: It seems that I get an error. The cause of the error seems to be from setContentView(R.layout.categoryselect); The error is android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class com.tdubstudios.soundboard.EDITNAMEFORONLINE.ScrollAbleLinearLayout

Comment: Do I have to add that java file to my manifest at all? The one that extends LinearLayout

Comment: No, no changes to the manifest. Can you edit your original post with the new XML file, as well as the `ScrollAbleLinearLayout` implementation? It could be something as simple as a missing closing tag, or a missed capital letter, or a typo in one of the names.

Comment: Sure I can do that. I figured the problem out though, and it is fixed in the above code. However that didn't help my situation at all, now the scrolling doesn't work and it doesn't ignore the buttons either. So it's as if I added nothing haha.

Comment: I've updated my code in the solution above, try that. I think I just had the `return` statement backwards...

Comment: Oh man you're awesome, to awesome. You've done exactly what I asked for. However I asked for the wrong thing, in a sense. So it does what I asked, it disabled the buttons and is tracking the listener as if the buttons aren't there. But thats exactly whats wrong as well. "As if the buttons aren't there". I also need the buttons to function correctly. I was trying to get both listener to work together at the same time. Maybe that's not possible though? Currently it works perfect, with the exception of my buttons are 100% disabled now. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've amended my solution above; is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I think I'm at the point of giving up. It doesn't seem worth it. The reason why I wanted all this is I have a bunch of buttons in a scrollView. I wanted to make it so when the user isn't currently scrolling, the buttons would go transparent so you can see the background. And when the user begins to interact with the scrollview (like start to scroll) they go back to 255 alpha (100% not transparent). I figured the ontouch and onrelease would be a good way to go about doing this. Would you agree or think my attempt at doing it this way is a complete fail way. I'm still new to android. Thanks.

Comment: Setting the alpha of so many items can be fatal. In a project of mine, I had approximately 120 items at 65% alpha, and the `ScrollView` lagged so badly it was unusable. (Also keep in mind the users may not understand why their buttons are see-through.) But here's what you could try; if it doesn't work, I would try a new idea instead of the alpha. In the `ACTION_DOWN` event, set the `ScrollAbleLinearLayout`'s alpha (not the `Button`s'), and in the `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL`, put it back. Then, return `false` as in my second example to ensure that the `Button`s receive their event.

Comment: returning false makes the buttons not work, and even though I have the if(event.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN){ return true } or up, the buttons don't ever seem to work. Makes me think the return true doesn't return true long enough. The changing alpha was more for effect but I've spent like 5 hours on this when honestly speaking it's pointless and doesn't effect anything but visual. I've edited my main post to show what I currently have.

Comment: Is there any type of method inside Activity that's like OnInteraction(boolean act) that just simply sees if the user is there, or if the screen is "idle"?

Comment: Oh man. I feel so bad. I've wasted your time and I figured out a method that will work. I'm going to use the Override method onTouchEvent. It will activate no matter were the user presses, not just on the scrollview but the only thing on my page is a scrollview and then a button above it. So yeah man so sorry for wasting your time. I'll make your answer the best answer, is there anything else I can do for you. I feel bad that you've spent so much time trying to help me when it was my fault.

Comment: No problem! I was just going to suggest a timer, or something. But, I would recommend hitting "Answer Your Question" at the bottom and posting that, and marking it as correct, so other users can find it.

Answer (score 0):

So I never really found the answer to my question, but I found a way that works. Instead of putting a listener on the layout, I am just adding the onTouchEvent method for the full activity rather than a specific view.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Toast.makeText(CategorySelect.this, "action DOWN called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Toast.makeText(CategorySelect.this, "action Up called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

It doesn't effect any of the buttons, so it's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much Soxxeh for working with me.